# Is there a way to change how a variable is stored in memory (bit sizes)?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, serial-port

Let's say I have the following datastructure (pseudo code):

```
struct
{
  uint8  id;
  bool   failure;
  uint8  value;
}
```

Now let's say I want the data stored in the following way in memory:

bit 7-6: id
bit 5: failure
bit 4-0: value

Is there anyway to do that in C/C++/Visual Studio? I know you can do it in Ada, but that doesn't mean much.

Edit:  Sorry for not being clear, I do need a particular layout in memory. This structure will be used for messages being sent across a serial channel and it needs to conform to the interface spec

Answer (score 7):

You can use C bitfields:

```
struct
{
  uint8 id : 2;
  bool failure : 1;
  uint8 value : 5;
};
```

However, although this *may* reduce the amount of memory used for the struct*, this does not guarentee any particular in-memory layout; the specific bits assigned for each field will depend on your compiler and/or platform ABI. If you need to assign specific bit indices to specific fields, you will need to pack and unpack manually. Or, if your code does not need to be portable, you could look up how your compiler packs bitfields, and order the members of your struct accordingly.

* - The C standard puts very few restrictions on the layout of bitfields, and C++ even less. Usually it will result in less memory usage, but if the compiler decides that the smallest bitfield allocation unit it'll use is a 32-bit field or something, then the size might actually increase. See ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) §6.7.2.1/10

Comment: `failure` ought to be a `uint8` as well, I believe.

Comment: @Ben, it doesn't really matter if you only use a subset of the bits in the fields.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I do need a particular layout in memory. This structure will be used for messages being sent across a serial channel and it needs to conform to the interface spec.

Comment: @Blindy: On some compilers, changing the type causes a new allocation unit to be started.

Comment: I wonder if anyone else finds it amusing that the answer that claims that there are 4 bits between 0 and 4 has twice as many votes as the next answer..

Comment: @Blindy, minor off-by-one error :) I would suspect the extra votes are because I touch upon how the actual in-memory layout is not specified.

Comment: @Blindly: Are you sure of that? Can you provide any reference from the standard? I have seen the behavior that @Ben points out in a few compilers, and I can give you an example where it does matter according with the standard: `struct test { int32_t a : 10; int32_t b : 20; int32_t c : 2; }`. If the types in the example are changed to `int16_t` the second element will have only 16 significant bits, if the type changes to `int8_t` then both `a` and `b` will have only 8 bits.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) §6.7.2.1/10 "An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a
structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is
implementation-defined. [...]"

Comment: @dribeas: The C++ standard leaves bitfield layout completely implementation-defined, except for the special-case of an anonymous zero-bit member.  Ironically, changing your example to `int16_t` will require more space on most compilers (6 bytes vs 4 with `int32_t`)

Comment: @Ben, it's not _completely_ implementation-defined. But there are quite a few parts that are implementation-defined, yes :)

Comment: @bdonlan: I missed a keyword in my earlier comment, was still able to add it.  The operative words are (from section `[class.bit]`): "Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is
implementation-defined.  Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined."

Comment: @Ben, is that from the C++ standard? I'm looking at C99 here :)

Comment: @bdonlan: Yup, you'll notice that the second word of my other comment mysteriously became "C++".  This question is tagged `visual-studio`, C99 doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: From the standard *The constant-expression may be larger than the number of bits in the object representation (3.9) of the bit-field’s type; in such cases the extra bits are used as padding bits and do not participate in the value representation (3.9) of the bit-field* Which means that if you use `uint16_t` to declare a bitfield of 20 bits, the effect is that 4 bits will only be used for padding, and will not participate in the value, i.e. `b` in the above example contains only 16 significant bits. The type in the bitfield declaration does matter.

Comment: @David: I agree.  It's just that that doesn't seem particularly relevant to this question.

Comment: @Ben, just stating that the types used in the bitfield declaration **do** matter (at least in that particular case) according to the standard, and I haven't been able to find any quote that stands by @Blindly statement that the types don't matter.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct
{
  int  id     :2;
  bool failure:1;
  int  value  :5;
}
```

Comment: While this meets the criteria, the structure itself will still be aligned by the compiler.  If the OP needs to save space, alignment should be forced.

Comment: @Chad, there's no such requirement in the OP's question.

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to point out to the OP -- usually when bit fields are used it is in an attempt to save space, and strictly putting them in place will not make the size of the structure go down, that has to be forced from alignment.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I do need a particular layout in memory. This structure will be used for messages being sent across a serial channel and it needs to conform to the interface spec.

Comment: It sounds like the device attached to the serial port wants to receive one byte.  The format of that byte is bits 7-6 is id, bit 5 is failure indicator, and  bits 4-0 is some value.

Comment: @mike, the structure in my answer is what you need.

Comment: I voted for this answer because it had the number of bits in `value` right, but the data types are all wrong (the question requires unsigned)

Answer (score 2):

For the raw data answer, you essentially put data in a `uint8_t` and use bitmasks and bitshifts to extract your data, an example implementation could be:

```
class MyData
{
private:
    uint8_t data;

public:
    MyData() : data(0) {}
    MyData(uint8_t id, bool failure, uint8_t value) : data(0)
    {
        Id(id);
        Failure(failure);
        Value(value);
    }

    uint8_t Id()
    {
        return (data>>6);
    }

    void Id(uint8_t id)
    {
        data &= 0x3F;
        data |= ((id&0x3)<<6);
    }

    bool Failure()
    {
        return (data & 0x20);
    }

    void Failure(bool failure)
    {
        if(failure)
        {
            data |= 0x20;
        }
        else
        {
            data &= 0xDF;
        }
    }

    uint8_t Value()
    {
        return (data & 0x0F);
    }

    void Value(uint8_t val)
    {
        data &= 0xF0;
        data|=(val&0xF);
    }

};
```

Let's take fore example the Id, you want to set the two highest order bits, bitmasked this is 0xC0. Of course youhave to shift it with the 6 bits down to get the actual value, otherwise you would for example get 128 iso 2. I dropped the mask because there are actually no higher order bits and the bithsift removes the lower orders.

Setting it is similar, you want to override previous data, which is instruction one (`ox3F==00111111b`), the and operator clears the parts that are 0 in the mask and does not touch the other bits. Instruction 2 uses the or operator to set the (previously cleared) high-order bits to the new value, and leaves the originals untouched, as the low-order bits are 0 and `a|0==a`.

The other parts are similar, hope this helps you on the way... .

So summarized, retrieving is "applying a mask and bitshifting", storing is "clearing bits with & and storing bits with |". Of course things get more complicated once you pass multi-byte values (you have to take endianness in account).

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using bit fields. In this specific case the C++ code would be:

```
struct
{
    uint8  value : 5; // bits 0-4
    bool   failure : 1; // bit 5
    uint8  id : 2; // bit 6-7
};
```

NOTE: Be sure to check you compiler documentation also since bit ordering and memory padding may affect portability. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field for more information or google for C++ bit fields.

Answer (score 0):

There are platform specific ways to make a struct pack that way.  If you want to follow the spec though, you'll have to pack it manually to a uint8 buffer or the like.  The compiler will respect the size of the fields in the other proposed solutions, but can pack them inside of the struct any way it chooses.  It could put unused padding in between the fields of the struct for speed optimizations for instance.